# gcc does not compile any other libraries in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c, gcc, visual-studio-code, mingw, vscode-tasks

I am on windows 10 and I use Visual Studio Code as IDE and code editor to code some C. I installed Microsoft's C/C++ extension as well as Jun Han's Code Runner.
I installed msys2 and then mingw64 in it. I added /mingw64/bin to the PATH.

The code compiles fine when standard libraries are included, but adding any other libraries (in my instance, GTK) makes compilation.
Here is my .vscode files :

.vscode\c_cpp_Properties.json :

```json
{
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "includePath": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/**",
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/include/**", //added by user
        "C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/**" //added by user
      ],
      "compilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
      "cStandard": "c99",
      "cppStandard": "c++11",
      "intelliSenseMode": "windows-gcc-x64",
      "compilerArgs": [
        "-Wall",
        "-Wextra",
        "-Wpedantic"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "version": 4
}
```

.vscode\settings.json :

```json
{
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cCompilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.cppCompilerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.debuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
  "C_Cpp_Runner.makePath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\mingw32-make.exe"
}
```

.vscode\tasks.json :

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe générer le fichier actif",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-Wall",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wpedantic",
                "-IC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\include\\**", //added by user
                "-LC:\\msys64\\mingw64\\lib", //added by user
                "-static" //added by user
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compilateur : C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        },
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe générer le fichier actif",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-Wall",
                "-Wextra",
                "-Wpedantic",
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "compilateur : C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

error message:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -g D:\Lycee\1G7\NSI\C\cc.c -o D:\Lycee\1G7\NSI\C\cc.exe -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -IC:\msys64\mingw64\include\** -LC:\msys64\mingw64\lib -static
cc1.exe: error: too many filenames given; type 'cc1.exe --help' for usage

La génération s'est achevée avec une ou plusieurs erreurs.
Échec du lancement du processus de terminal (code de sortie : -1).
```

folder structure:

```
        Directory : C:\msys64\mingw64
Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        09/05/2021     13:12                bin
d-----        09/05/2021     13:04                etc
d-----        09/05/2021     13:04                include
d-----        09/05/2021     13:12                lib
d-----        09/05/2021     13:02                libexec
d-----        09/05/2021     13:02                share
d-----        09/05/2021     13:01                ssl
d-----        09/05/2021     13:01                var
d-----        09/05/2021     12:52                x86_64-w64-mingw32
```

```
    Directory : C:\msys64\mingw64\include\gtk-3.0\gtk


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
d-----        09/05/2021     13:02                a11y
d-----        09/05/2021     13:02                deprecated
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3570 gtk-a11y.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          12188 gtk-autocleanups.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           9820 gtk.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          10179 gtkaboutdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8707 gtkaccelgroup.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4247 gtkaccellabel.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3992 gtkaccelmap.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2812 gtkaccessible.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3730 gtkactionable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2913 gtkactionbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5997 gtkadjustment.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1777 gtkappchooser.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4470 gtkappchooserbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3617 gtkappchooserdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5384 gtkappchooserwidget.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7330 gtkapplication.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3525 gtkapplicationwindow.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3054 gtkaspectframe.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          10946 gtkassistant.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4946 gtkbbox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2651 gtkbin.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7039 gtkbindings.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2137 gtkborder.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5221 gtkbox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8159 gtkbuildable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          10511 gtkbuilder.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6751 gtkbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6812 gtkcalendar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          34828 gtkcellarea.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3652 gtkcellareabox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7354 gtkcellareacontext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2757 gtkcelleditable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7767 gtkcelllayout.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          17871 gtkcellrenderer.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3483 gtkcellrendereraccel.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2550 gtkcellrenderercombo.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2596 gtkcellrendererpixbuf.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2918 gtkcellrendererprogress.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2461 gtkcellrendererspin.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2744 gtkcellrendererspinner.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2828 gtkcellrenderertext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3652 gtkcellrenderertoggle.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4960 gtkcellview.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2963 gtkcheckbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4152 gtkcheckmenuitem.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          12479 gtkclipboard.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4612 gtkcolorbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3353 gtkcolorchooser.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2627 gtkcolorchooserdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2762 gtkcolorchooserwidget.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1762 gtkcolorutils.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8511 gtkcombobox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4419 gtkcomboboxtext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          11423 gtkcontainer.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4570 gtkcssprovider.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3876 gtkcsssection.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2704 gtkdebug.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7808 gtkdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4117 gtkdnd.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4412 gtkdragdest.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2779 gtkdragsource.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2516 gtkdrawingarea.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4835 gtkeditable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          18620 gtkentry.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6320 gtkentrybuffer.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           9523 gtkentrycompletion.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          36978 gtkenums.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3116 gtkeventbox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2772 gtkeventcontroller.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2860 gtkeventcontrollerkey.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2241 gtkeventcontrollermotion.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3758 gtkeventcontrollerscroll.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4985 gtkexpander.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          13213 gtkfilechooser.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3944 gtkfilechooserbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2782 gtkfilechooserdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2392 gtkfilechoosernative.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2705 gtkfilechooserwidget.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4613 gtkfilefilter.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3141 gtkfixed.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          11754 gtkflowbox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4685 gtkfontbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7387 gtkfontchooser.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2768 gtkfontchooserdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2806 gtkfontchooserwidget.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3641 gtkframe.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4923 gtkgesture.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2462 gtkgesturedrag.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2131 gtkgesturelongpress.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2461 gtkgesturemultipress.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2335 gtkgesturepan.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2180 gtkgesturerotate.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3071 gtkgesturesingle.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2453 gtkgesturestylus.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2286 gtkgestureswipe.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2126 gtkgesturezoom.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5489 gtkglarea.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5828 gtkgrid.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4130 gtkheaderbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          17261 gtkicontheme.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          14988 gtkiconview.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7733 gtkimage.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5292 gtkimcontext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1243 gtkimcontextinfo.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2868 gtkimcontextsimple.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1222 gtkimmodule.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2883 gtkimmulticontext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5298 gtkinfobar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2784 gtkinvisible.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           9051 gtklabel.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4182 gtklayout.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4740 gtklevelbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3564 gtklinkbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          14290 gtklistbox.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5881 gtkliststore.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2579 gtklockbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7241 gtkmain.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          11177 gtkmenu.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3272 gtkmenubar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4033 gtkmenubutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6679 gtkmenuitem.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5496 gtkmenushell.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3484 gtkmenutoolbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5363 gtkmessagedialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1962 gtkmodelbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1822 gtkmodules.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3442 gtkmountoperation.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2926 gtknativedialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          11517 gtknotebook.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2623 gtkoffscreenwindow.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2330 gtkorientable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3324 gtkoverlay.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3906 gtkpadcontroller.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5566 gtkpagesetup.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4417 gtkpaned.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5186 gtkpapersize.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8627 gtkplacessidebar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3329 gtkplug.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4828 gtkpopover.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2188 gtkpopovermenu.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2935 gtkprintcontext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          15897 gtkprintoperation.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3375 gtkprintoperationpreview.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          16089 gtkprintsettings.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4347 gtkprogressbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4145 gtkradiobutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4025 gtkradiomenuitem.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3302 gtkradiotoolbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7883 gtkrange.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          10056 gtkrecentchooser.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3082 gtkrecentchooserdialog.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2924 gtkrecentchoosermenu.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2760 gtkrecentchooserwidget.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5531 gtkrecentfilter.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          10122 gtkrecentmanager.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8237 gtkrender.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3450 gtkrevealer.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4914 gtkscale.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4384 gtkscalebutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3224 gtkscrollable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2497 gtkscrollbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          10046 gtkscrolledwindow.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3390 gtksearchbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2735 gtksearchentry.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          12769 gtkselection.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2578 gtkseparator.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2762 gtkseparatormenuitem.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2916 gtkseparatortoolitem.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6035 gtksettings.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2462 gtkshortcutlabel.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1830 gtkshortcutsgroup.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1896 gtkshortcutssection.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3404 gtkshortcutsshortcut.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2128 gtkshortcutswindow.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1509 gtkshow.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3177 gtksizegroup.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2010 gtksizerequest.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2918 gtksocket.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7981 gtkspinbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2473 gtkspinner.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6580 gtkstack.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2656 gtkstacksidebar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2624 gtkstackswitcher.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3729 gtkstatusbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          36417 gtkstylecontext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4796 gtkstyleprovider.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3304 gtkswitch.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4289 gtktestutils.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8312 gtktextattributes.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          21622 gtktextbuffer.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7623 gtktextbufferrichtext.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3093 gtktextchild.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4445 gtktextdisplay.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          16376 gtktextiter.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          20587 gtktextlayout.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4768 gtktextmark.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5154 gtktexttag.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3852 gtktexttagtable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          22305 gtktextview.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3881 gtktogglebutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3275 gtktoggletoolbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5400 gtktoolbar.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4540 gtktoolbutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6124 gtktoolitem.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           5649 gtktoolitemgroup.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8012 gtktoolpalette.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           4210 gtktoolshell.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2899 gtktooltip.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6130 gtktreednd.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          15729 gtktreemodel.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7649 gtktreemodelfilter.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3806 gtktreemodelsort.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           7316 gtktreeselection.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6316 gtktreesortable.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           6455 gtktreestore.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          28132 gtktreeview.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          13126 gtktreeviewcolumn.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          20740 gtktypebuiltins.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2544 gtktypes.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3369 gtkversion.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3724 gtkviewport.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           2550 gtkvolumebutton.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          67581 gtkwidget.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           8856 gtkwidgetpath.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43          21244 gtkwindow.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           3224 gtkwindowgroup.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1078 gtkx-autocleanups.h
-a----        23/04/2021     10:43           1064 gtkx.h
```

I tried a lot of different solutions over the past two days, and I ran out both of ideas and websites to look at. I'm sure I have done some stupid mistake somewhere, but I can't find where.
Also, ideally, getting rid of unnecessary arguments would be nice (if I can get it to work that is).

Comment: Don't post images of the errors, copy-paste them into your post.

Comment: Don't use images of text like code or error messages. Even the directory contents can be shown as the output of a `dir` comman (in `cmd`) or `ls` command (in a MSys or MinGW `bash`). Please [edit] your question and copy&paste everything as text, formatted as separate code blocks. Tell in your question where the file `gtk/gtk.h` is on your system. I don't know if vscode can use wildcards like `.../**`. Maybe you have to specify all individual directories. A `.../lib` directory is probably wrong in the list of include directories. You might have to specify it as a library path.

Comment: Those `-I...` and `-L...` flags should be completely unnecessary, since those directories are searched by default. Install `pkg-config` from MSYS2, and use it to determine which flags you need to pass for the libraries you want.

Comment: I would recommend not adding compilers to the PATH as you can inadvertantly have problems caused by multiple different parts of compiler being found , and these are hard to debug

Comment: `**` in the compiler commandline is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer I came up with:

tasks.json :

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe générer le fichier actif",
            "command": "gcc -Wall -g ${relativeFile} -o ${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe  `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`",
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "shell": {"executable": "bash.exe", "args": ["-c"]},
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "compiler : C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
        },
    ]
}
```

It may not be that good of an idea though, because it requires bash to be installed as well. It feels hacky and improper, but it works for me.